# Can't change UITableView to edit Mode and back again

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiview, edit

I't trying to change the tableView to edit mode, by looking at the code I have everything needed... but I guess not.

```
    final class InboxViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var inboxViewComponent = InboxViewComponent()
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
        }
    
        override func loadView() {
            super.loadView()
    
            view = inboxViewComponent
        }
    
    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            // Takes care of toggling the button's title
            super.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
    
            inboxViewComponent.tableView.isEditing = true
        }
    }


final class InboxViewComponent: UIView {
    let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = Constants.tableSectionHeight
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.backgroundColor = ColorEnum.grey08
        tableView.register(InboxCellUIKit.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: Constants.cellIdentifier)
        tableView.register(UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: Constants.cellHeaderIdentifier)
        tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        return tableView
    }()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.pin(.all).to(self)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.datasource = self
    }
}
```

Comment: I can’t see where you’ve set the table view’s delegate to the view controller (usually self). Have you forgotten to do this or have you done it inside of code which is not shown above? (I believe this is required for editing and as you have not used the preset UITableViewController you’ve used UIViewController this is required to be done by you.) I’m assuming you have set the table view’s data source to the view controller (usually self) or you would be having issues with your data not displaying within your table view.

Comment: @Demented07 the code is in `InboxViewComponent`, I forgot to had it here but it's on the project. Thanks